# Not able to edit phone number for User verification in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

This is in reference to the User verification using DocuSign, I am trying to explore the Phone Authentication mode, but I am not getting an option to edit the number/ Choose a new number on the Screen where  DocuSign requests for  the Access code , I have set the recipMayProvideNumber": to true, but it does not seems to be working , Please help

Comment: are you using the API? writing code? or you are asking about using the web app?

Comment: I am using the DocuSign API

Comment: Here is the request

Comment: "phoneAuthentication": {
    "recipMayProvideNumber": true,
    "senderProvidedNumbers": [
    "+91-987-123-1456"
    ]
   },
   "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
   "requireIdLookup": true

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-implementing-docusign-recipient-authentication) on the topic of recipient authentication.
The number should be passed during the API call like you did. You cannot change it as the signer, only the sender can modify it.
If you want to modify it, you need to make a PUT request to the envelope before it is sent. Once set you can still change it but that would require a new email to also be sent out, the original email with the original link would be invalidated.

Comment: Thanks for the link but i was not able to locate the information that only sender can modify the number, is there any other Documentation which would suggest the same

Comment: I can look, but think about it, it's a security feature to prevent fraud. If the signer can modify the number - it defeats the purpose. Say someone hacked my email, they get the notification, change the number to their own and they can now sign for me. The whole point is to avoid that by using 2FA